# How do I grep files with .mp3 but not .mp3.RegFr?

Tags: ubuntu, grep, wildcards

I have files `ABC.mp3`, `ABC.mp3.RegFr`. I want to grep files with `.mp3` and not `.mp3.RegFr`. Can anybody help?

Comment: Why do you want to grep an MP3 file? Are you trying to search inside the ID3 tags?

Comment: Do you want to grep the contents of the actual .mp3 files? or grep a list of filenames for filenames ending in .mp3?

Comment: I want to grep the filenames ending with .mp3

Comment: It is still unclear why you would need `grep` here, if you can simply use `ls -l *.mp3`. If you are looking for files based on their name, take a look at `find`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a Linux system, you can use `*.mp3` to grep all files ending with `.mp3`.

Note however, that mp3-files are binary files, not text files. You will probably need to instruct `grep` to search through a binary file, as in

```
grep -a searchpattern *.mp3
```

Note 2: If you want to look at the id3tag, you're better off with `id3info`.

--- edit ---

As per comments, the OP does not want to grep the mp3-files, but rather grep the output of `ls`. Although there are some issues with parsing the output of `ls`, it is possible with

```
ls | grep 'mp3$'
```

Explanation: for `grep`, the `$` sign represents the end of the line. So you're selecting the lines that end with `mp3`.

You can also let the shell do the selection, like in

```
ls *mp3
```

or

```
ls -1 *mp3
```

Here the shell will expand `*mp3` to a list of files that end with `mp3`. That list of files is given as arguments to ls. The `-1` forces a single column output (see `man ls`)

Comment: These are my mp3 filenames names along with its metadata filenames inside my audio folder.

Comment: I tried the command : ls | grep '*.mp3' . It's not working..

Comment: ls | grep -v '*.mp3' <br> no luck with this command either

Comment: That is not what you asked.  You asked to grep the mp3-files, not the  grep of the output of `ls`. If that is what you want, do `ls *mp3` or `ls | egrep  'mp3$`

Comment: `<br>` is HTML and has no meaning here. Even worse: the `<` and `>` are here unquoted, and therefore seen by the shell as IO redirection.

Comment: <br> wasn't part of the command..I used it for this website but no luck here either.